# Unable to see the posted message in facebook immediately

Tags: java, restfb

I wrote a small message and I posted to facebook wall. When I try to view this post message using the following code to search post messages:

```
public Connection<Post> searchMessages() {
    Connection<Post> messages = publicFbClient.fetchConnection("search",
            Post.class,
            Parameter.with("q", "Testing"),
            Parameter.with("limit", "100"),
            Parameter.with("type", "post"));
}
```

I don't see the message(s) immediately after posting, but are seen after a little while. Is there a delay in fetching FB messages, if so how much OR is there a problem with my query being issued from a certain timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1000's of messages waiting to get served i.e. to get displayed. So some delay is bound to happen. Similar behavior as SO where after posting your question, there is a delay when it appears to everyone.

So this does not depend on the time zone but on the load on the servers..

Comment: I am observing considerable amount of delay (more than 30-45 minutes), would that be the case here? I wouldn't mind if its within few minutes.

Comment: I think that would be dependent on how efficient your search method is... If your search is trying to search a pin in a haybarn, it would definitely take considerable time!!